# How to add a button to the Action menu?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo, odoo-view

I want to add new button in action

[image]

Comment: Look for it in [the documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/) please or [here](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_4_module_development/action_creation.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `key2="client_action_multi"` in act_window to add submenu to "Action" button ("More" in previous Odoo versions). Reference [here](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_4_module_development/action_creation.html)

```xml
<act_window name="New Sub menu"
    res_model="product.product"
    src_model="product.product"
    key2="client_action_multi" 
    view_mode="form" target="new" 
    view_type="form"
    id="act_new_sub_menu" />
```